# Mongodb aggregation with age range

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Hello guys I'm trying to make a simple aggregation query to get all the users within an age range.

The document data looks like this:

```js
{"_id":"5b9a111108467610980b6771","data":{"Name":"Alex","age":46}}
```

And the query I have tried is that:

```js
db.mongo_test.aggregate([{ $match : { data : {age: { $range: [ 0, 50 ] }} } }])
```

I tried also $group without success.

I know it's supposed to be easy so I must be missing something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `.find` with `$and`, `$lte` and `$gte` operators

```
db.mongo_test.find({
    $and: [{
        "data.age": {
            $gte: 0
        }
    }, {
        "data.age": {
            $lte: 50
        }
    }]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The most easiest way to find:

> db.mongo_test.find({ "data.age": { $gte: 0, $lte: 50 } })